# Spring Integration FTP remove local files after use (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to write a program that can take a file from one server via ftp and place it on another server via ftp. However, I am having issues deleting the local file after it has been written. Being able to save it locally is not an issue as long as it is temporary. I have tried using an ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice with an OnSuccessExpression and I could not get it to actually use the expression. The code is here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FTPConnectionProperties.class)
public class FTPConfiguration {

    private FTPConnectionProperties ftpConnectionProperties;

    public FTPConfiguration(FTPConnectionProperties ftpConnectionProperties) {
        this.ftpConnectionProperties = ftpConnectionProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpInputSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(ftpConnectionProperties.getInputServer());
        sf.setUsername(ftpConnectionProperties.getInputFtpUser());
        sf.setPassword(ftpConnectionProperties.getInputFtpPassword());
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(sf);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpOutputSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(ftpConnectionProperties.getOutputServer());
        sf.setUsername(ftpConnectionProperties.getOutputFtpUser());
        sf.setPassword(ftpConnectionProperties.getOutputFtpPassword());
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(sf);
    }

    @Bean
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpInputSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(ftpConnectionProperties.getInputDirectory());
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.TIF"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "input", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(ftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("ftp-inbound"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), ""));
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        FtpMessageHandler handler = new FtpMessageHandler(ftpOutputSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(ftpConnectionProperties.getOutputDirectory()));
        handler.setFileNameGenerator(message -> {
            if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {
                return ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload.");
            }
        });
        return handler;
    }

}
```

It is handling the remote files exactly as expected, deleting the remote file from the source and putting into the output, but not removing the local file after use.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make that `input` channel as a `PublishSubscribeChannel` and add one more simple subscriber:

```
@Bean
public PublishSubscribeChannel input() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}


@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    ...
}


@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
public MessageHandler deleteLocalFileService() {
    return m ->  ((File) message.getPayload()).delete();
}
```

This way the same message with the `File` payload is going to be sent first to your `FtpMessageHandler` and only after that to this new `deleteLocalFileService` for removing the local file based on the payload.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I managed to solve this using a PseudoTransactionManager to delete the local file once the FtpMessageHandler completes its process successfully. Would this behave in a similar way or would it remove the file locally regardless?

Comment: Yes, that's good approach, too. If you configure to delete only on the transaction commit, then it is really going to work the same way. When exception happens, no delete and TX is rolled back.

Comment: @ArtemBilan how does the method deleteLocalFileService() get invoked? Does one have to invoke it somewhere manually in another method?

Comment: Why is the question if there is that `@ServiceActivator` to consume messages from the `input` channel? You probably need to make yourself familiar with Spring Integration framework : https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution to fetch file from SFTP server and then move that file to other folder with different name.**

```
   @Bean
        public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
            DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);

            if (sftpServerProperties.getSftpPrivateKey() != null) {

                factory.setPrivateKey(sftpServerProperties.getSftpPrivateKey());
                factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(sftpServerProperties.getSftpPrivateKeyPassphrase());
            } else {
                factory.setPassword(sftpServerProperties.getPassword());

            }
            factory.setHost(sftpServerProperties.getSftpHost());
            factory.setPort(sftpServerProperties.getSftpPort());
            factory.setUser(sftpServerProperties.getSftpUser());

            factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);

            return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
        }

        @Bean
        public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
            SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
            fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
            fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpServerProperties.getSftpRemoteDirectoryDownload());
            fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(sftpServerProperties.getSftpRemoteDirectoryDownloadFilter()));
            return fileSynchronizer;
        }

        @Bean
        @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fromSftpChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "*/10 * * * * *"))
        public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
            SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                    sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
            source.setLocalDirectory(util.createDirectory(Constants.FILES_DIRECTORY));
            source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
            return source;
        }

        @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromSftpChannel")
        public MessageHandler resultFileHandler() {
            return (Message<?> message) -> {
                String csvFilePath = util.getDirectory(Constants.FILES_DIRECTORY) + Constants.INSIDE + message.getHeaders().get("file_name");
                util.readCSVFile(csvFilePath, String.valueOf(message.getHeaders().get("file_name")));
                File file = (File) message.getPayload();
                File newFile = new File(file.getPath() + System.currentTimeMillis());

                try {
                    FileUtils.copyFile(file, newFile);
                    sftpGateway.sendToSftp(newFile);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }
                if (newFile.exists()) {
                    newFile.delete();
                }

            };
        }

        @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannelDest")
        public MessageHandler handlerOrderBackUp() {
            SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
            handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
            handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(sftpServerProperties.getSftpRemoteBackupDirectory()));
            return handler;
        }


        @MessagingGateway
        public interface SFTPGateway {
            @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannelDest")
            void sendToSftp(File file);


        }
```